# GMS DM-script - Lineplot add secondary intensity axis

Tags: dm-script

Is it possible, using a dm script, to add a secondary intensity axis to a lineplot and assign
parameters in the plot to this secondary axis?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GMS up to version 3.4 does not support dual-axis line plots.

---

But it is possible to change the displayed scale and offset of individual slices in the display (both X&Y).  The shown intensity axis, however, is fixed to one of those slices.

See example below:

- Left: Two (identical) spectra in one plot
- Right: Same spectra (still identical values!), but the 2nd display slice has changed scale and offset. The intensity axis is the one form the 1st slice and has not changed.

Example:[image: Example]